# how can I add multiple levels to each category

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have multiple locations under the location column, then I want to add group numbers within each location. But number of groups is different in locations.

e.g. df1

```
Location
Chicago
Minneapolis
Dallas
.
.
.
```

and df2

```
Location      times
Chicago         2
Minneapolis     5
Dallas          1
.               .
.               .
.               .
```

What I want to get is:

```
Location   Group
Chicago      1
Chicago      2
Minneapolis  1
Minneapolis  2
Minneapolis  3
Minneapolis  4
Minneapolis  5
Dallas       1
.
.
.
```

What I have now is... repeating same number of groups among the locations: 17 groups within each location. But I just realized there will be different groups among locations... then I don't know what to do next.

```
filled_results['location'] = results['location'].unique()
filled_results['times'] = 17
filled_results = filled_results.loc[filled_results.index.repeat(filled_results.times)]

v = pd.Series(range(1, 18))
filled_results['group'] = np.tile(v, len(filled_results) // len(v) + 1)[:len(filled_results)]  

filled_results = filled_results.drop(columns=['times'])
```

I was thinking about a for loop, but don't know how to achieve that. for each unique location within df1, giving them 0 to x of groups based on #ofgroups in df2.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution myself. It's very easy if considering this as add index within each group. Here's the solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['location'] = df1['location'].unique()
df = pd.merge(df,
              df2,
              on = 'location',
              how = 'left' )
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.times)]

df["Group"] = df.groupby("location")["times"].rank(method="first", ascending=True)

df["Group"] = df["Group"].astype(int)
df = df.drop(columns=['times'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this code.

```py
data = [
  { 'name': 'Chicago', 'c': 2 },
  { 'name': 'Minneapolis', 'c': 5 },
  { 'name': 'Dallas', 'c': 1 }
]

result = []

for location in data:
  for i in range(0, location['c']):
    result.append({ 'name': location['name'], 'group': i+1 })
```

`result` will be:

```
[{'group': 1, 'name': 'Chicago'}, {'group': 2, 'name': 'Chicago'}, {'group': 1, 'name': 'Minneapolis'}, {'group': 2, 'name': 'Minneapolis'}, {'group': 3, 'name': 'Minneapolis'}, {'group': 4, 'name': 'Minneapolis'}, {'group': 5, 'name': 'Minneapolis'}, {'group': 1, 'name': 'Dallas'}]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your quick answer! But what if my data and result both are dataframe? I was trying to apply the same for loop using data as dataframe, but it is keep giving me an error.
```
for i in range(0, location['c']):
```
**TypeError: string indices must be integers** I would greatly appreciate if you could help!

Comment: @StephanieG I'm sorry, but I don't know about Dataframes.